# AWS Lambda Functions: it doesn't show list of existing roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have created a Role in `IAM` with `AmazonEC2FullAccess` based policy. This role is properly created in `IAM`. But the same role is not appearing to attach for `lambda` function.

Can someone please help. I have the admin access and with this I'm getting below error.

`(AccessDenied) when calling the PutMetricAlarm operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/lambdaEC2fullaccess/StopEc2 is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/aws-service-role/events.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForCloudWatchEvents"`

[image: ImageWithAccessRole]

[image: RolesNotAppearingInLambda]

Answer (score 6):

From your screenshot, it appears that the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` **role is for EC2 instance**, not lambda. You can verify this by going into the IAM console, clicking on the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` and checking its **trust relationship**.

If the trust policy is for instance, it will look like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, **IAM trust policy for lambda** should look like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can edit the trust policy, and refresh your lambda console window. Or you can create new role for lambda from the beginning.